# Solr - Storing offsets and positions of numericValues

Tags: lucene, indexing, offset, numeric, solr4

Just would like to know if it is possible to store the offsets,positions and frequencies of numeric values of int,float,double types in Solr. For terms, we have character and token attributes to which offsets can be set but for numeric values, while storing as Trie or Sortable, Is it possible to set the offset or attributes for the same?

I have tried considering payloads and payload filters but not able to understand which one would be best for this and also whether it is possible to perform range queries on payload values.

Otherwise, there is also the use of IndexOptions for setting this:DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS to the field.But again not sure if this is applicable for anything other than terms/characters.Another candidate, NumericTermAttribute doesnot have position or attribute set functions.

It is fine to store them the numeric values as terms and perform sortable str search sort but why would i do that when i have a Trie which is more efficient considering the performance?